# How to resolve extern variable from dlopen'd library

Tags: linux, g++, dlopen

Is it possible have a global variable defined inside an application, accessed by a shared library that has been loaded with dlopen()?

I have it declared as an extern but when the app loads and tries to use it I get an undefined symbol error.

I am loading the library with flags set to RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL.

Comment: hmm, looks like I might be able to provide a getter for the symbol by a function I can place in the app that loads the library.

Comment: Wait, is the global variable actually defined in the library, or in the application? Did you define it extern in the application?

Comment: It's a global defined inside the app but defined as an extern in the library itself.

Answer (score 3):

You have to you build your application where you have a global variable with `-rdynamic` option for `g++`. This option instructs the linker (`ld`) to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table of your application.

This is an example how I build my test C++ application that loads a shared library. The shared library uses a global variable in `main.cpp`. So I have added `-rdynamic` when build my `main` application:

```
g++ -rdynamic  -m64 -g main.cpp -o main -ldl
```

When `g++` finds `-rdynamic` it passes the flag `-export-dynamic` to the ELF linker (`ld`). 
This is from `man ld` (which actually creates the dynamic symbol table):

> If you use "dlopen" to load a dynamic object which needs to refer back
>   to the symbols defined by the program, rather than some other dynamic
>   object, then you will probably need to use this option when linking
>   the program itself.

Useful links:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Link-Options.html
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld